# Updating hooks from v2 to v4

Tags: add-on-development, extension, hook

My company has a legacy add-on from version 2 and has now updated to version 4 of EE.
With the upgrade, the hooks that fire when a new entry of a specific channel type are no longer triggering.

After some research, it looks like the issue that the hook names are wrong. The code defining them is below.

```
   public function activate_extension() {
   
       // Setup custom settings in this array.
       $this->settings = array();
       
       $entrySubmissionBeginHook = array(
           'class'     => __CLASS__,
           'method'    => 'entrySubmissionBegin',
           'hook'      => 'entry_submission_ready',
           'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
           'version'   => $this->version,
           'enabled'   => 'y'
       );
       
       $entrySubmissionEndHook = array(
           'class'     => __CLASS__,
           'method'    => 'entrySubmissionEnd',
           'hook'      => 'entry_submission_end',
           'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
           'version'   => $this->version,
           'enabled'   => 'y'
       );
       
       $deleteEntriesStarthook = array(
           'class'     => __CLASS__,
           'method'    => 'deleteEntriesStart',
           'hook'      => 'delete_entries_start',
           'settings'  => serialize($this->settings),
           'version'   => $this->version,
           'enabled'   => 'y'
       );
       
       ee()->db->insert('extensions', $entrySubmissionBeginHook);
       ee()->db->insert('extensions', $entrySubmissionEndHook);
       ee()->db->insert('extensions', $deleteEntriesStarthook);
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were certainly several extension hook changes with the arrival of EE3, possibly with EE4 too, so you may well need to update the naming of the hooks in your addon.

You can find a complete list of the hooks available in EE 4 [in the documentation](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/development/extension_hooks/index.html).

HTH

Comment: Thanks. As I said, I'm pretty new to this, would the member_* hooks be what I'm looking for when I need to hook into a a new post being saved/updated? https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/development/extension_hooks/global/member_model/index.html#legacy-member-model-extension-hooks

Comment: No - you'd want the [channel entry hooks](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/development/extension_hooks/model/channel-entry/index.html) - probably [after_channel_entry_save](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/development/extension_hooks/model/channel-entry/index.html#id6) which covers both new entries and updates to existing ones and [after_channel_entry_delete](https://docs.expressionengine.com/v4/development/extension_hooks/model/channel-entry/index.html#id8).  Or if you don't want to change your code simply find the nearest equivalents to the hooks you are currenlty using... HTH